# Blankscreen after session login

Tags: boot

I have seen many post here about it but nothing specific to my problem. I have tried too many things to list here.

So ill try to be simple:
Once i get the session screen where you login, i go straight to a blank screen.
If i go to F1 i can run startx and get into the desktop.

> -I have tried reinstalling all possible packages i have found on the  internet :( bringing new issues that need fixing which i can fix but
>   not the blank screen. (ex: unity,lightdm,ubuntu-desktop,gnome-*, etc)
>
> -a new users same
>
> -reinstalling nvidia drivers same.
>
> -switch to gnome3 instead of lightdm same problem.
>
> -i notice that most of people ask for xorg.0.log but i would prefer for someone that really understand this to point me properly.

Thanks in advance, any advice is welcome
Ubuntu 16.06

Comment: are you using wayland? i had similar problem in kde plasma. it was caused because i switched to wayland in settings. removing wayland from terminal tty session restored me into xorg and i felt saved.

Comment: I dont think i have that running on my ubuntu 16.06. it seems for newer versions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After not finding a solution, i give it a shot to do-distro-upgrade command which upgraded from 16.06 to 18 now everything works as expected.

:)